# How to get the integers entered but it says it is in string format?

Tags: python

```
num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
num3 = input("Enter third number: ")
num4 = input("Enter fourth number: ")
num5 = input("Enter fifth number: ")
print("\n")
print("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d" %("num1,num2,num3,num4,num5"))
```

Results:

```
Enter first number: 90
Enter second number: 98
Enter third number: 94
Enter fourth number: 98
Enter fifth number: 99
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string. You need to cast it to an int using the `int()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use them as integers later on, you'll need to convert the input to int type like this:

Also, natice that the quotes around the variable in the string formatting have been removed. The quotes were causing the python interpreter to think it was just being passed a single string.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter third number: "))
num4 = int(input("Enter fourth number: "))
num5 = int(input("Enter fifth number: "))
print("\n")
print("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d" %(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5))
```

If you don't need to use the input as integers later on you can just leave them as strings and change the string formatting to use them as strings:

```
num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
num3 = input("Enter third number: ")
num4 = input("Enter fourth number: ")
num5 = input("Enter fifth number: ")
print("\n")
print("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" %(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not know how to format a string by that way you can use

> format  (method)  with your string.

```py
num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
num3 = input("Enter third number: ")
num4 = input("Enter fourth number: ")
num5 = input("Enter fifth number: ")
print("\n")
print("{},{},{},{},{}".format(num1,num2,num3,num4,num5))
```

it is better than that way. i think

Answer (score -1):

The numbers that you entered into the console were considered as strings. You need to cast them into 'int'.

`print("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d" % (int(num1), int(num2), int(num3), int(num4), int(num5)))`